# ActivityFeeds.Plugin.ActivityClose stops record creation, How to solve it?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Some times the ActivityFeeds.Plugin.ActivityClose plugin gets registered on the wrong entity and it stops me from creating new records for that entity.
It usually happens after I register a new plugin with the Plugin Registration Tool.

What is the cause? and how do I solve it?

Comment: the cause is that after you register or update a plugin the first assembly is selected (and often is the ActivityFeeds one) so accidentally you add a step to the ActivityFeeds assembly instead one the one you just registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the cause, or how to solve it for good, but to make it work again is simple:

- Log into the Plugin Registration Tool.
- Select View->Display by Entity(Ctrl+Shift+E).
- Expand the entity you are having trouble with.
- Expand (message)Create.
- Finally select the step for ActivityFeeds.Plugin.ActivityClose and Disable it.
  --(Don't Unregister it [in case something breaks])

Answer (score 0):

disable/unregistered the following like steps in plugin **ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose**

```
ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose: Update of  any Entity
```

**CAUSE**

This kind of steps is registered unintentionally when we do some thing like below in screen shots:

Following is the plugin **ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose**, you can see there is no step registered for this plugin.

[image]

Registered an assembly.

[image]

Right click on assembly name not on plugin, select registered new step.

[image]

Just enter update in message field and then press enter

[image]

you can see a step `ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose: Update of  any Entity` is added to  **ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose**

[image]